# Android drawing an arc in custom view using sweep gradient with multiple colors

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I'm trying draw a custom view which has an Arc which will be filled with gradient of 4 colors and I choose SweepGradient to be suitable for this and when I tried it works fine for two colors and even if add more colors I'm not able to get the other two colors. I tried different combinations of positions as well nothing seem to work.

```
         int colorRes[] = {R.color.yellow, R.color.green,R.color.oragne, R.color.red};    
         float stops[] = {0,0.3f,0.6f,1};
         int colors[]  = new int[colorRes.length];
            for(int i=0;i<colorRes.length;i++){
                colors[i]= context.getResources().getColor(colorRes[i]);
            }
        Shader gradient = new SweepGradient (wdith/2,height/2, colors, stops));
        lighted.setShader(gradient);
        canvas.drawArc(rectf, 130, 280, false, lightRed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the actual issue was because of a bug in Android Studio which has not been fixed yet.

Please look at the issue reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194448)

The rendering of SweepGradient in layout preview fails in Android Studio where as **in real device it was working fine.**

I realized that its always good to test customviews in real devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. And the reason why that happened on my side is - the width and the height was 0.

So in reality doing this -

```
new SweepGradient (wdith/2,height/2, colors, stops));
```

I got this -

```
new SweepGradient (0,0, colors, stops));
```

So to be sure that the width and height wasn't 0 I did it like this -

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mShader == null) {
            float cX = getWidth() / 2F;
            float cY = getHeight() / 2F;
            mShader = new SweepGradient(cX, cY, getRingColors(), null);
        }
        testPaint1.setShader(mShader);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.status_ring_dimen), testPaint1);
    }



private int[] getRingColors() {
        return new int[]{
                getResources().getColor(R.color.md_blue_500),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.md_red_400),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.md_green_500),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.md_blue_500) 
// the first and last color should be the same to get a smooth transition of colors

        };
    }
```